Why is 'marry' used in the passive voice here?
This is from a web page.

After six of their players were married during and after the 1888
season, the club was called the Bridegrooms. In '91, after John
Montgomery Ward became manager, the nickname “Ward’s Wonders” was
used. In 1893, Dave Foutz became manager and the team’s nickname
became “Foutz’s Fillies.”

I'm curious why 'marry' is used in the passive voice in this context, even though it can also be used as an intransitive verb.

Did you look in a dictionary? It's quite common. "They were married in a private ceremony".

What do you think it should be? "After six of their players married" might sound like they got married to each other.

@Astralbee Thank you very much

@StuartF Thank you very much
